# How I can define both http and ssh for the same VCS definition in composer.json?

Tags: php, http, ssh, composer-php

In my composer.json I define a vcs repository as:

```
{
    "repositories":[
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:vendor/secret.git"
      }
    ]
}
```

But some prefer using username and password whereas some do provide an ssh key upon their user. Therefore, I want also to define the same VCS repo via http as well so for the same package either http or ssh will be used.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying multiple repository entries, each with a different URL format. Something like this:

```
{
    "repositories":[
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:vendor/secret.git"
      },
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/vendor/secret.git"
      }
    ]
}
```